# Can't return response from redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm calling an action from a component:

```
this.props.createWebsite(this.state)
```

This calls an action and passes in some state. The action looks like this:

```
export const createWebsite = data => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.post(
        API.path + 'website/', 
        {
            // some data
        }
    )
    .then(response => {

    })
    .catch(error => {

    })
  }
}
```

I want to handle the response and error in the component that called this, rather than in the action itself. How can I do this? I have tried:

```
this.props.createWebsite(this.state).then(response => { /**/ }).catch(error => { /**/ })
```

This *sort of works* but it doesn't catch errors.

Comment: For catching errors you must use the `catch` method: `this.props.createWebsite(this.state).then(response => { /**/ }).catch(error => { /**/ })`

Comment: typo in my code above! I am using the catch method :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the catch from the `createWebsite` declaration.

It handle the error and to not propagate it. So the error is lost.
To get it :

### remove the catch

```
export const createWebsite = data => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.post(
        API.path + 'website/', 
        {
            // some data
        }
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response;    
    })
  }
}
```

### rethrow the exception

```
export const createWebsite = data => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return axios.post(
        API.path + 'website/', 
        {
            // some data
        }
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Do something
      throw error;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I'm not sure why. If an error is returned, why can't this be passed directly back to whatever called it? Why must another error be explicitly thrown in order to achieve this?

Comment: To pass it directly to the caller you have to remove the `catch` (first solution). The catch stops the propagation of the error in the promises chain.

Comment: The solution solution with throw is usefull when you want a common behaviour of the errors (logs by example)